# What is the JavaScript while loop doing here?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

What is this JavaScript code doing here, specifically the while loop:

```
function setAjaxLinks(){
    var links = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var linkL = links.length;

    while (linkL--) {
        if (!links[linkL].href.match('#')) {
            mj.pageLoad(links[linkL]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware "mj" doesn't really mean anything, but what is the general gist?

Comment: This should be using `for` instead of `while`

Comment: @Shaz Not always, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It loops through all links (a-tags) on the page from the last to the first (decrementing).

If it finds a link that doesn't have a `#` symbol in it, it calls the `mj.pageLoad` function with the link in question as parameter.

Here's a blow by blow:

```
function setAjaxLinks(){
    //find all <a> tag elements on the page
    var links = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    //get the amount of <a> tags on the page
    var linkL = links.length;
    //loop over all <a> tags on the page from last to first
    while (linkL--) {
        //if the href attribute on the current <a> tag has a # sign in it
        if (!links[linkL].href.match('#')) {
            //then call this function (and from the name of the function convert it to an ajax call) 
            mj.pageLoad(links[linkL]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression:

```
linkL--
```

decrements `linkL` by one and returns the previous value of `linkL`.

The expression:

```
while (someIntValue) { ... }
```

runs the body of the loop while `someIntValue` is not `0`. It is equivalent to:

```
while (someIntValue != 0) { ... }
```

So:

```
while (linkL--) { ... }
```

will run the loop with `linkL` (inside the loop) varying from its initial value minus one, to zero, inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reverse while which is faster than "for" in many/most cases:  see here for citation: http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a reverse `for` loop. Starting at the "top" and counting down until it reaches 0. In situations where the order of execution isn't relevant it's more efficient that a `for`loop.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it iterates through the collection `links`, and checks if they include a `#`.

`linkL` stores the length of the collection. The `while` checks the boolean value of this variable, then decrements it by one. So when `linkL` reaches zero, it will still run, and in the next turn zero will evaluate as `false`, so it stops.

If you check `linkL` after the `while`, it will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a page preloader.

The `while` loop decrements `linkL` until it reaches 0 and iterates over every `a` tag.